# Insert a background picture in beamercolorbox?

Tags: beamer, graphics

As the title states. Is there a way to insert a background picture for a beamercolorbox. I mean I can make two of them overlap or something, but can I insert a background picture somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update:

Using the newest version of `tcolorbox` (`2.32 (2013/06/23)`), the `beamer` skin works fine with watermark clipping:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,hooks}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\tcbset{colframe=structure,fonttitle=\bfseries,beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A color box with a background image}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title={The title},watermark graphics=mushrooms,
watermark opacity=0.5,watermark color=blue,watermark stretch=1]
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily do this by simulating the `beamercolorbox` with the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package; the `skins` and `hooks` libraries allow you to insert a background image (there's even a `beamer` skin that will give the look and feel of `beamer` settings for boxes); setting a value of `1` for `watermark stretch`, the image will occupy the entire box.

A little example; I used a (famous by now) [`Wikipedia image`](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Mycena_interrupta.jpg), renaming it to `mushrooms`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,hooks}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\tcbset{colframe=structure,fonttitle=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A color box with a background image}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title={The title},watermark graphics=mushrooms,
watermark opacity=0.5,watermark color=blue,watermark stretch=1]
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The rounded shadow is not really adapted to the angle of the image.

Comment: @PaulGaborit you're right; I've changed the example, since the `beamer` skin apparently don't cooperate well with the `watermark` inclusion.

Comment: Until version 2.31, `tcolorbox` did not support direct clipping of watermarks, i.e. a watermark could overlap the frame if large enough. Version 2.32 adds switchable clipping support for watermarks and clipping is the default behaviour. This new version will be published in a few days.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Ah, that explains it. Thank you! I'm looking forward to seeing the new version. `tcolorbox` has greatly evolved and has become a powerful package.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've just uploaded `tcolorbox` 2.32 with 'clip watermark' as one of the additions :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Great! I'll be checking updates on the mirrors. Thank you very much for letting me know.

Comment: @PaulGaborit as anounced by `tcolobox`'s author, with the newest version, the `beamer` skin now does a proper watermark clipping (see my updated answer).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Perfect!

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out at the earliest! This looks great.